# SQL server Login Fail for user 'ROMANCH9326/romanch'

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, authentication, sql-server-2012

I installed SQL server 2012 developer addition.

My windows is working on Parallel Access installed on MAC.

When I tried opening SQL server, It initiated a call to connect to server. And when I clicked on connect it gave me error.

I've never installed SQL server 2012 in my personal PC. WHen I was installing I chose Windows authentication mode and user ROMANCH9326 came out automatically.

Please help me, I'm clueless about this problem.

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to ROMANCH9326.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   Login failed for user 'ROMANCH9326\romanch'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

Comment: I have posted error in bold text. please look for bold text above to understand the error message.

Comment: Since the problem [disappeared after reinstalling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28861624/3717023), it does not appear to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

On Start > Search type "sql configuration"

Open SQL Configuration Manager

SQL Server Network Configuration >Protocols for [SQLINSTANCENAME]

Check if Named Pipes is enabled, enable it if not.

Restart your SQL Server Instance.

Comment: I enabled the Named Pipes. Then restarted everything under **SQL server services**. But still error continues.

Comment: can you try changing the server name to (local)?

Comment: Well I guess the best solution is to re-install.  If there's a button "Add current user", make sure to click it.

Comment: I remember when i installed it, I chose Add Current user. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Well This is a pretty silly solution but when I tried repair function on SQL server it said that my Database Engine libraries were not installed properly somehow.

So I reinstalled the software and now it worked just fine. I was able to log in.

Thanks :)